# Conditionally changing only some cells in a data frame - ifelse() failure?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditionally change some items when cleaning survey data.

I've got two questions, Question X and Question Y. If they respond 1 or 2 for Question X, they go on to answer Question Y. If they answer 3 or 4 for Question X, they skip Question Y.

If they answer X with 1 or 2 and then skip Y, I want to record their 'NULL!' entries as NA - they just didn't answer the question when they should have. 
If they answer X with 3 or 4 and then skip Y, I want to record their 'NULL!' entries as 0 - they weren't supposed to answer the question, so they didn't.

Here's a reproducible dataset I made:

```
  set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  X = as.factor(sample(c("1.00", "2.00", "3.00", "4.00"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
  Y = as.factor(sample(c("1.00", "2.00", "#NULL!"), 10, replace = TRUE))
)
df
```

I'm trying to replace the aforementioned 'NULL!' fields with either NA or 0 respectively. I've been trying it with ifelse() and have had little luck - it appears to return anything that is 1.00 or 2.00 as NA and 3.00 or 4.00 as 0. Is there a better way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

```
levels(df$Y) <- c(levels(df$Y), 0)
    df$Y <- ifelse(df$X == '3.00'| df$X == '4.00', df$Y[df$y == 'NULL!'] <- 0, df$Y[df$Y == '#NULL!'] <- NA)
    df
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Remember to check the checkmark next to the answer below that answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a couple of things the hard way. First, using factors constrains one to only use levels that exist in the a particular factor, which may not be what you want. Second, you have levels of "#NULL!" but are attempting (unsuccessfully) to test for a level of "NULL!". I'm guessing you wanted them to be the same level. Third; You are attempting to use "<-" inside the second and third arguments of `ifelse`. That will not succeed in manner you intended. The LHS of such an expression is not evaluated by `ifelse`.

You can instead use nested `ifelse`:

```
df$Y <- ifelse( (df$X == '3.00'| df$X == '4.00') & df$Y == "#NULL!", 0,  
                     ifelse( df$Y == "#NULL!", NA, df$Y) ) # only mess with "Nulls"

df
      X    Y
1  2.00 1.00
2  2.00 1.00
3  3.00    0
4  4.00 2.00
5  1.00 <NA>
6  4.00 2.00
7  4.00    0
8  3.00    0
9  3.00 2.00
10 1.00 <NA>
```

To prevent the missing levels problem which you handled by adding a "0" level, I instead made my dataframe so it contained character vectors:

```
set.seed(1)
 df <- data.frame(X = sample(c("1.00", "2.00", "3.00", "4.00"), 10, replace== TRUE),
                  Y = sample(c("1.00", "2.00", "#NULL!"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Earlier tidyverse code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(Y = case_when(
  X == "3.00" ~ "0",
  X == "4.00" ~ "0",
  TRUE ~ as.character(Y)))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I definitely see where I was overcomplicating things here. This worked very well for me!

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for me - for some reason it wasn't sending anything to 0, it was making things that should have been 0 go to NA. Not sure why. The comment that actually worked was the one recommending Tidyverse, but that comment appears to have been deleted.

Comment: Didn't work? Means what? Need explanation.  It's possible than my comment about correctness to the tidyverser caused the deletion. I said it appeared that you didn't want df$Y changed if it already had a value other than "#NULL!". If that's not what was intended then you should clarify the question and put in what you think should be the right answer.

Comment: Your answer didn't work because for some reason it would not make any values that should have been 0 become 0 - everything either stayed as 1.00 or 2.00 or went to NA. I have no explanation for why it didn't work. The Tidyverse solution worked for me with slight modification - I changed the end statement to  `TRUE~as.character(Y)` and then changed everything that was leftover as a "#NULL!" value to NA via `df$Y[df$Y == '#NULL!'] <- NA`. I know this also isn't probably the ideal method, but it worked for me.

Comment: The reason is how ifelse acts with factors. It was actually screwing things up completely.  Instead first convert to character and then do the transformation. I put the tidyverse code up so you can play with it, but I don't think it's correct either.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  X = as.factor(sample(c("1.00", "2.00", "3.00", "4.00"), 10, replace = TRUE)),
  Y = as.factor(sample(c("1.00", "2.00", "#NULL!"), 10, replace = TRUE))
)

df$X <- as.character(df$X)
df$Y <- as.character(df$Y)

df$Y <- ifelse(df$X=="1.00" | df$X=="2.00" & df$Y == "#NULL!", NA, df$Y)

df$Y <- ifelse(df$X=="3.00" | df$X=="4.00", "0.00", df$Y)
df

      X    Y
1  2.00 1.00
2  2.00 1.00
3  3.00 0.00
4  4.00 0.00
5  1.00 <NA>
6  4.00 0.00
7  4.00 0.00
8  3.00 0.00
9  3.00 0.00
10 1.00 <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This also worked, but I went with the next comment's solution for space saving reasons.

Comment: @anongard: This would have the advantage of demonstrating the correct way to convert the working columns from factor to character (which you handled by adding a "0" level), although it appears to not yield the correct answer.

Comment: The comment that actually worked best was the one recommending Tidyverse, but that comment appears to have been deleted.